# In SQL Server Management Studio 2018 unable to find "Device" on restore database screen

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, restore

I am trying to restore "wideworldimporters-Full.bak" database in management studio 2018. The instructions to restore it states to select device option which I don't see on restore database screen. Instead, it has backup file browse option which I tried but it gives a system error that it cannot find the file (I think it is looking for .abf file).

I would appreciate any help in restoring the database so that I can follow the PBI course.

Comment: Hi Cetin,

On the left there is only "General" for selection. There are no other options like  Files, Options which I see in your restore database screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Object Explorer (left) right click "Databases" and select "Restore Database". In the dialog that pops up, be sure on the left "General" is selected and you should see the "Device" option then.

[image: Select restore database]

[image: Select device]

Comment: Hi Cetin, On my restore database screen on the left there is only "General" for selection. There are no other options like Files, Options which I see in your restore database screen.  I don't know how to upload the image otherwise I would have done it to show what I mean.

Comment: @Ibr, is your SQL server a local one or not (ie: azure database)? How did you connect, do you have the permission to restore a database? To upload an image, click the picture icon in reply mode and drag & drop your screen shot file.

Comment: Thanks Cetin. Today, when I opened SQL Server Managment Studio, my restore database screen (on right clicking the databases and selecting the restore database option) I got the same screen as shown by you, so I was able to restore the database. I still don't know why the same screen was not displayed last time! In any case, I appreciate your assistance.